# Angular: How to check the http code after a post or put request?

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api

Here's my server-side code

```
[HttpPut("api/columnInfoData")]
public IActionResult UpdateColumnInfoData([FromBody] KeyValue[] columnInfoList)
{
    try
    {
        _unit.ColumnInfos
                .UpdateColumnInfoData(columnInfoList);
        _unit.SaveChanges();

        return NoContent ();
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
        return BadRequest();
     }
}
```

And this is my Angular code:

```
updateColumnInfos(_url: string, body) {
return this.http.put(this.baseUrl + _url, body)
  //.do(data => console.log('getKeyValues: ' + JSON.stringify(data)))
  .map((event: HttpEvent<any>) =>{
    console.log(event.type)
  })
  .catch(this.handleError);
```

}

This the subscribe part..

```
 updateColumnInfos(){
 this._backendService
    .updateColumnInfos("api/columnInfoData", this.tempColumnIdList)
    .subscribe(success => {
      if(success){

      }
    }, err => this.errorMessage = "failed to update column selection")

    //this.reloadTable = false;
  }
```

Unfortunately, it's not logging anything. When I put a break point in my C# code, the breakpoint is being hit. When I make the request through `Postman`, I'm getting a `204`.

How to check the code in my angular code? In fact, I want to reload a table after a successful columns update.

Thanks for helping

## EDIT

Instead of `return NoConent()`, I'm returning `return Ok("Test...");`, but my angular code is still logging nothing. However, when I go to the browser: `F12 > Network tab > Response tab`, I see `Test...`

## EDIT 2

Instead of returning a string `Ok("test...")` to creating an anonymous object `Ok(obj)`, now it's logging. Is there any reason?

```
public IActionResult UpdateColumnInfoData([FromBody] KeyValue[] columnInfoList)
{
    try
    {
        _unit.ColumnInfos
                .UpdateColumnInfoData(columnInfoList);
        _unit.SaveChanges();

        //return Ok("test..."); --> I've changed this to ..
        var resp = new { resp = "test..." };
        return Ok(resp);
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
        return BadRequest();
     }
}
```

Comment: which version of angular? is this httpclient or http service?

Comment: Are you calling Subscribe()? The code you've included wont actually make the http request.

Comment: in the package json it's said: `^5.0.0` and this is the statement `import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';`

Comment: @Steveland83, please see code I added.

Comment: Thanks. Perhaps its to do with the `NoContent()` response (just a guess), have you tried returning `Ok()` ?

Comment: I've changed it to Ok() but nothing is happening.

Comment: is the request´ firing?

Comment: Yes. When I run in debug mode, the breakpoint is being hit in the backend with the expect data being sent.

Comment: `if (success) { console.log(success); }` does that give you anything? Don't think you need `.map` and `.catch` in your service code if using `HttpClient`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Angular's documentation](https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response), something like the following should do the trick.

```
updateColumnInfos(_url: string, body) {
  return this.http
             .put(this.baseUrl + _url, body, {observe: 'response'})
             .subscribe(resp => console.log(resp));
```

You can look in your dev tools for the `resp` properties, but most likely `resp.statusCode` will be what you are looking for.

Comment: It seems like `{observe: 'response'}` works only with `get`

Comment: hmm, thats curious as it is documented as being on all the methods. here is put: https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#put